# How to manipulate a particular IP address that is taken from route table in Bash Script

Tags: bash, ip

I'm trying to write a network scanner in Bash Script. where I'm taking an IP from the route table (IP of my router), but now I want to delete the last digit of that IP and put a letter so that I can able to put that IP address in a loop to generate a more sequential IP address.

this is the code I'm talking about:

```
first_ip=$(route -n | awk 'NR>2{print $2}' | head -1)
```

Now, what to do to delete the last character of that IP?

Comment: You might try to use the dot as a separator and replace $4 by the mentioned letter. Would that work?

Comment: With GNU awk: `route -n | awk 'NR==3{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {NF--}1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **remove** the last part of the **IP-addresses** by using `grep`:

`first_ip=$(route -n | awk 'NR >2 { print $2 }' | head -1 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}")`

This gives you the first three numbers of the IP-address listed by `route-n`.
You can then add any numbers XXX that you wish like so:

```
first_ip=$(route -n | awk 'NR >2 { print $2 }' | head -1 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}")
first_ip = first_ip"XXX"
```

So if you have the IP-address **192.155.177.123** you get **192.155.177.**
you can then add any number that you want to add...

I hope this helps!